# Remove last distinct K character(s) from end of a string

Tags: regex, perl

How to I remove G s at the end of each string, and capture string left of it. 
    ...TGTGGG 
    ...CTGAGGGGG 
    ...ACAGGGGGGGG 
    ...CAAACAGGGGGGGGGGGG

The result would like this. If possible I want to capture this remaining string in a regex. 
    ...TGT 
    ...CTGA 
    ...ACA
    ...CAAACA 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing trailing `G`s is easy.

```
s/G*$//
```

If it's not necessarily a `G`, you can match it with a capture group.

```
s/(.)\1*$//
```

If you want to only remove a character if it is *repeated* at the end (so `ATCG` would be untouched but `ATCGGG` would change), you can do that with `+`

```
s/(.)\1+$//
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. Is there a drawback doing this m/([ATGC]*?)G*$/. It seems to give the same result. It's [ATGC]*? part that I had hard time to figure out until I see your answer.

Comment: That would work perfectly well. `m//` won't modify the original string, whereas `s///` will actually change the string in-place, so it depends on what you want out of it.